# Explicit vs Implicit return

Tags: ruby

In the case below, the loop exits upon answering `"yes"` or `"no"`.

```
def ask question
  while true
    puts question
    answer = gets.chomp.downcase

    if answer == "yes"
        return true
    elsif answer == "no"
        return false
    end
    puts "Please answer \"yes\" or \"no\"."
  end
end

ask('hello')
```

When the `return` statements next to the boolean values are removed, the last `puts` (`please answer ...`) is printed in the console, and the loop is then executed again.

A loop should break when anything is returned (either explicitly or implicitly) or when there is a break defined, correct? What's different when there is explicit returns in this case?

Comment: There is no difference between implicit and explicit `return`. There is no **implicit** `return` before the boolean values. Having no `return` and having a `return` (either implicitly or explicitly) are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A methods ends when one of the following occurs

- *Immediately* when the thread terminates
- *Immediately* when a `raise`/`throw` is encountered - excepting as such is handled
- *Immediately* when a `return` is encountered
- When it runs out of code or "reaches the end", in which case the value of the last expression is returned

The immediate forms end the method immediately (no surprise), while simple pure expressions such as `true` or `false` as appearing by themselves on a line by themselves (read: an expression) *mean nothing* unless such values are themselves used - but this is not done the return is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if simplifying the code a bit can give a clearer picture:

```
if answer == "yes"
  return true
elsif answer == "no"
  return false
end
puts "something"
```

is the most relevant part here.  With the explicit `return`, the code exits from the method and never reaches the `puts`.  The return value is therefore `true` or `false`.

Without the explicit `return`:

```
if answer == "yes"
  true
elsif answer == "no"
  false
end
puts "something"
```

The `true` and `false` statements merely exit the `if-else` code and executes the `puts`, the return value of which is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

An explicit return will return from the ENTIRE method, it doesn't matter if the loop is finite or infinite, if it's in a method, return will stop right there and return. Yes, you're right, the loop should also break from the loop. You can also specify an argument to the break which will be the return value of the entire loop.